# android GMP cross compilation

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling, gmp

I'm on debian/amd64 and I want to cross-compile GMP for android 2.2 using NDK-7b. I took the source code from [gmplib](hg clone http://gmplib.org:8000/gmp-5.0 gmp).
I configured it with:

```
./configure --enable-shared --host=arm-linux-androideabi --prefix=/home/fabien/android/spica/ndk-standalone-8 CFLAGS="-v -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -Wl,-rpath,lib/ -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -Wall -O3 -nodefaultlibs -fPIC -shared -Wl,--no-allow-shlib-undefined" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/fabien/android/spica/ndk-standalone-8/lib/pkgconfig" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link -Wl,/home/fabien/android/spica/ndk-standalone-8/lib -L/home/fabien/android/spica/ndk-standalone-8/lib"
```

I modified the file config.h by setting:

```
/* Define to 1 if you have the `obstack_vprintf' function. */
#ifndef ANDROID
#define HAVE_OBSTACK_VPRINTF 1
#endif
/* Define to 1 if you have the `localeconv' function. */
#ifndef ANDROID
#define HAVE_LOCALECONV 1
#endif
/* Define to 1 if you have the `vsnprintf' function and it works properly. */
#ifndef ANDROID
#define HAVE_VSNPRINTF 1
#endif
```

I updated the SUBDIRS parameter as follows in Makefile:

```
 SUBDIRS = tests mpn mpz mpq mpf printf scanf cxx mpbsd demos tune
```

It seems to compile when I run make:

```
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libgmp.so" && ln -s "libgmp.so.10.0.5" "libgmp.so")
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libgmp.la" && ln -s "../libgmp.la" "libgmp.la" )
```

But when I run "make check", the linker seems lost:

```
/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: warning: ld-linux.so.3, needed by /home/fabien/android/spica/sources/gmp/.libs/libgmp.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
t-bswap.o:(.ARM.exidx.text.main+0x0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0'
./.libs/libtests.a(misc.o):(.ARM.exidx.text.align_pointer+0x0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0'
.
.
.
refmpn.c:(.text.refmpn_get_str+0xb8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
refmpn.c:(.text.refmpn_get_str+0x238): undefined reference to `__aeabi_ui2d'
refmpn.c:(.text.refmpn_get_str+0x250): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
refmpn.c:(.text.refmpn_get_str+0x254): undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2uiz'
./.libs/libtests.a(refmpn.o):(.ARM.exidx.text.refmpn_get_str+0x0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0'
/home/fabien/android/spica/sources/gmp/.libs/libgmp.so: undefined reference to `abort@GLIBC_2.4'
/home/fabien/android/spica/sources/gmp/.libs/libgmp.so: undefined reference to `puts@GLIBC_2.4'
```

Any hints ?

Comment: Fabien R, did you figure out exactly how to do the compilation? I'm trying to compile GMP as well for Android, but to no success. Do you happen to remember what your procedure was?

Comment: @NicoBellic: No. Maybe you'll get lucky with the latest NDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is due to the fact that the file that contains these helper functions (these are GCC helper functions) is not being included when the linker creates the target. To fix this, please add the *libgcc.a* (which contains the GCC helper function definitions) into the linker flags.

As for the location of libgcc.a, assuming gcc version arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3, it will be 
`$NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/libgcc.a`

This will **NOT** fix the following errors(which seem to be related to the GNU libc being missing):

```
.libs/libgmp.so: undefined reference to `abort@GLIBC_2.4'
.libs/libgmp.so: undefined reference to `puts@GLIBC_2.4'
```

The above 2 errors will always show up as android uses the Bionic libc, and not the GNU libc

Note: This method will fix similar issues on all systems, not just Android.

Comment: I saw this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919710/about-arm-eabi-gcc-and-cross-compiling).Since I'm using the NDK standalone compiler, I added "-nostdlib" to CFLAGS,  "-L/home/fabien/android/spica/ndk-standalone-8/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3" to LDFLAGS and LIBS="-lgcc -lm -ldl -lc". But I got this output : arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: warning: libm.so.6 , needed by ... gmp/.libs/libgmp.so. The linker could not laso found ld-linux.so.3 and libgcc_s.so.1. Moreover, I got this message: ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 000096cc

Comment: The start symbol comes from one of the following files (depending on what the target is an executable or a library): crtbegin_dynamic.o (executabe dynamic linked), crtbegin_static.o (executable static linked), crtbegin_so.o (dynamic library). add the path of the correct object as part of the input to LD, and you should have sorted out the _start symbol error

Comment: I solved the error about the symbol _start by replacing -nostdlib by -nodefaultlibs. But the linker seems still lost when launching "make check". configure recognized it as GNU compliant.

Comment: Ok, I found my mistake. I add the option -std=c99 and removed all references containing -Wl. It works with this command:<code> ./configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux-androideabi --prefix=/home/fabien/android/spica/ndk-standalone-8 CFLAGS="-v -std=c99 -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -Wall -O3 -nodefaultlibs  -fPIC -shared "</code>

Comment: @FabienR did you suceed in making a reproducible, preferably automated build with shared and static libs for armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86 and x86_64?